# Does this theorem hold for a different metric?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

My teacher recently proved that:

> Let $(E_1 ,d_1)$ and $(E_2.d_2)$ be metric spaces and $f,g: E_1 \rightarrow E_2$ continuous functions, then $h: E_1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $h(x)= d_2(f(x),g(x))$ is continuous.

And her proof was:

Let $\varepsilon >0$ and $x_0 \in E_1$, because $f,g$ are continuous then there exist $\delta_1>0$ and $\delta_2 >0$ such that:

$$d_1(x,x_0)<\delta_1 \implies d_2 (f(x),f(x_0)) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} $$
$$d_1(x,x_0)<\delta_2 \implies d_2 (g(x),g(x_0)) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} $$

Then let $\delta = min\{\delta_1 , \delta_2 \}$, then if $d_1(x,x_0) < \delta$ then:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
|d_2(f(x),g(x))-d_2(f(x_0),g(x_0)| &= |d_2(f(x),g(x))-d_2(f(x),g(x_0)) +d_2(f(x),g(x_0)) -d_2(f(x_0),g(x_0)| \\
&\leq |d_2(f(x),g(x)) - d_2 (f(x),g(x_0))| + |d_2(f(x),g(x_0)) -d_2(f(x_0),g(x_0) | \\
&\leq d_2(g(x),g(x_0)) + d_2(f(x),f(x_0)) <\frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon
\end{split}
\end{equation}

But we asked her if this holds for a different metric for $\mathbb{R}$ and she said she thought so but she wasn't sure, so my question is does it hold for other metric? I am struggling to find a proof of that (if that's the case). Thank you in advance.

Comment: What other metrics on $\mathbb{R}$ are you thinking about? For example, do you want to restrict attention to metrics inducing the usual topology (in which case the answer is yes since continuity depends only on topology)?

Comment: I haven't learned a lot about topology because I am in a introductory course to analysis so I have been thinking about the basic examples such as the discrete metric. I haven't been able to prove it or refute it using only the properties of a metric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counter-example: Take $E_1=E_2=\mathbb R$ with the usual metric, $f(x)=x$ and  $g(x)=0$. Let $\phi$ be any bijection of $\mathbb R$ such that $\phi (0)=0$ but $\phi (\frac  1n )$ does not tend to $0$. [You can take $\phi (x)=\frac 1 x$ for $x \neq 0$ and $\phi (0)=0$].  Conider the metric $D(x,y)=|\phi(x)-\phi(y)|$. Then $h$ is not continuous w.r.t this metric on its range because $h(\frac 1 n)$ does not tend to $0$ w.r.t. $D$.

Comment: @absolute0 $E_1=E_2=\mathbb R$ with the usual metric . Why isn't the identity function continuous? The new metric appears only at the end when we consider $h: (E_1,d_1), \to (\mathbb  R, D)$.